# Oracle Linux 6.7 - How to extend ext4 disk

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, oracle-linux

We have an Oracle Linux 6.7 server. Let the server IP be 10.55.5.10. There is a 350GB disk on this server. And shared over NFS with another Oracle Linux 6.7 server with 10.55.5.11 IP.

NOTE: these are virtual machines running on VMware.

`df --inodes` output below:

```
Filesystem       Inodes   IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1      22937600 5450823 17486777   24% /data/upload
```

`df -hP` output below:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       345G  321G  6.7G  98% /data/upload
```

`cat /etc/fstab` output below:

```
/dev/sdb1               /data/upload         ext4    defaults        0 0
```

This disk is unfortunately not lvm. There is even no disk configured as lvm on the server. The commands I specified below yield no results:

```
[root@ol67 ~]# pvdisplay
[root@ol67 ~]# vgdisplay
[root@ol67 ~]# lvdisplay
[root@ol67 ~]#
```

`tune2fs` output below:

```
[root@ol67 ~]# tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1 | grep resize_inode
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
```

`fdisk -l` output below:

```
[root@ol67 ~]# fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 375.8 GB, 375809638400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 45689 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00010620

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1       45690   367001568+  83  Linux
```

`showmount` output below:

```
[root@ol67 ~]# showmount -e
Export list for ol67.domain.com:
/another_disk 10.55.5.11
/data/upload  10.55.5.11
```

There are 27 subdirectories under /data/upload. And in one of these subdirectories there are another 1 million subdirectories. NOTE: I wanted to point out that maybe it is an important detail.

I don't know how I can expand a non-LVM disk. Is it possible to expand an ext4 type disk on Oracle Linux 6.7?

Best regards,

Comment: You've used the entire space on the 350GB disk. Assuming this is a physical machine and not a VM, how would you be proposing to expand the disk drive?

Comment: @roaima it's a virtual machine.

Comment: What's your VM hosting environment (HyperV, ESXi)?

Comment: @roaima I don't know. It's my clients' server. The Virtual Machine on VMWare.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend filesystem partition on Ubuntu VM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196512/how-to-extend-filesystem-partition-on-ubuntu-vm)

Comment: @roaima They talked about gparted. I know a little about the parted command on Oracle Linux. Currently, there are 750GB disks on the server, not partitioned and ready to use. I looked at what I can do with the help command. I need to set up and review an R&D machine, I hope it works.

Comment: You didn't give any indication of your level of expertise. You didn't include things you'd considered. If I'd jumped right in with delete the partition that holds all your data and recreate it, someone unfamiliar with the process would quite reasonably be alarmed. Nevertheless, if you have a possible solution they're great. Go for it. With a backup of your data.